# Add Eventlistener to control HTML5-Audio

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I really really tried hours now, to find the answer myself, but I just don't know how to solve this. I'm absolutely new to javascript.

My Task: I want to control an HTML5-Audio Element with JavaScript. My first steps are:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">  
document.getElementById("myAudio").addEventListener('onpause', function(){
alert("Paused!");
getElementById("myAudio").play();
alert("Playing again!");

}, false);

</script>
</head>

<body>

<audio id="myAudio" controls autobuffer  >
<source src="Test.mp3" />

</audio>
</body>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems like there is no event called...

Another thing I wonder about is, that Chrome does display the audiocontrol. But Firefox (FF 11) just displays an empty page.

I just don't get it, I spent hours now and tried many alternatives... I really hope that someone can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support MP3 format. Use an other audio file format like OGG.

Add a new source tag with this different file format:

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls autobuffer  >
    <source src="Test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="Test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#MPEG_H.264_%28AAC_or_MP3%29

Use one of available online/offline tools to convert your file to OGG format:

- http://media.io/
- http://ffmpeg.org/
- http://www.videolan.org/
- http://www.mediacoderhq.com/

Comment: thank you! this explains why this doesn't work in firefox!

My initial intention was to control an HTML5-Audio Element with JavaScript. Unfortunately this doesn't work wih the code I inserted above. It seems like there is no event called... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "pause" is correct name of event, not "onpause"
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#mediaevents

Comment: thank you! I was looking here, unfortunately: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: W3School website give attributes name, but not event name. So it will work like that: `<audio onpause="alert('pause')">...` and `audioDOMO.addEventListener('onpause', function(event){alert('pause')}, false);`